# При активации 6-ти checkbox скрыть старые дивы и показать новый

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

У меня есть шесть дивов и на них есть чекбоксы. Как сделать, чтобы эти дивы скрывались когда на всех стоят галочки, а появился один большой новый?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под **появился один большой новый**

Comment: код пожалуйста ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9424uzon/8/ 
Чтобы эти скрылись и над ними появился один большой и было написано "Выполнено"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    <div class="checkbox-block-info" style="display: none">
        Выполнено
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-block">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
    <div class="checkbox-block-info" style="display: none">
        Выполнено
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-block">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.checkbox-row').on('change', function(){
        var block = $(this).parents('.checkbox-block');

        if (block.find('.checkbox-row').length == block.find('.checkbox-row:checked').length) {
            block.siblings('.checkbox-block-info').show();
            block.hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```